# Django FOREIGN KEY constraint failed

Tags: django, sqlite

My app is a shopping cart. I have a function in views.py that is triggered when someone adds an item to the cart. The function checks if the user has an active order (one that is in the cart but hasn't been paid for).
But the code fails at `user_order, status = Order.objects.get_or_create(owner=user_profile, is_ordered=False)

```
@login_required()
def add_to_cart(request, **kwargs):
    #get the user profile
    user_profile = get_object_or_404(UserProfile, user=request.user)

    #filter products by id
    producto = Producto.objects.filter(id=kwargs.get("pk", "")).first()
    #create OrderItem, of the selected product
    order_item, status = OrderItem.objects.get_or_create(producto=producto)
    if status == False:      #adds one to the order_item
        order_item.quantity += 1
    order_item.save()

    print(order_item.quantity)
    #create order associated with the user

    user_order, status = Order.objects.get_or_create(owner=user_profile, is_ordered=False)

    user_order.items.add(order_item)

    #print(user_order.items.all()) #queries the items
    #print(user_order)
    #date is not beign added
    # generate a reference code
    user_order.ref_code =random.randint(0,100000)
    user_order.save()

    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
```

Relevant models:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    fecha_reparto = models.OneToOneField(DiasDeReparto, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default= 1)
    order_nodo = models.OneToOneField(Nodo, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default= 1)
    ref_code = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(OrderItem)
    date_ordered = models.DateTimeField(null=True)

    def get_cart_items(self):
        return self.items.all()

    def get_cart_total(self):
        return sum([item.producto.precio * item.quantity for item in self.items.all()])

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ref_code

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    producto = models.OneToOneField(Producto, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null = True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    is_ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    date_ordered = models.DateTimeField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.producto.nombre
```

Comment: Please show the full error and traceback.

Comment: What's the error message when it fails? Are you using `PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;` [Docs](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html)

Comment: traceback: http://dpaste.com/2Z1J7AP

Comment: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed is the error message

Comment: Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/add_to_cart/3
Django Version: 2.1
Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value: 
FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
Exception Location: C:\Users\Gonzalo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py in _commit, line 239
Python Executable: C:\Users\Gonzalo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe
Python Version: 3.6.4

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be solved with something like this:

```
try:
        Order.objects.get(owner=user_profile)
    except:
        Order.objects.create(fecha_reparto=dia_reparto[0], order_nodo=nodo[0], ref_code="asdas", owner=user_profile, is_ordered=False, date_ordered=datetime.datetime.now())
```

But I don't get why get_or_create doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

On your Order model you have a few related model fields and in the get_or_create you are not specifying any defaults. The get or create needs the required values to input if creating and you have a few related fields which are required. That will also explain why the try and except works because you add the fields when creating in the except.

```
defaults = {fecha_reparto: dia_reparto[0], order_nodo: nodo[0]......}
user_order, status = Order.objects.get_or_create(owner=user_profile, is_ordered=False, defaults=defaults)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `id` instead model instace in this line:

```
user_order, status = Order.objects.get_or_create(owner=user_profile, is_ordered=False)
```

So it should look like this:

```
user_order, status = Order.objects.get_or_create(owner_id=user_profile.pk, is_ordered=False)
```

It worked for me with similar problem.